# How can I fetch data from my firebase storage when just data changed? Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm currently doing some testing on my project. In my firebase storage, I have a database of about 4 MB. As a test, when I press a button, I pull this database to the phone. The problem is, when I press button, the data is being rewritten. This is the waste of internet package. I want, when I press the button, if the data has changed, it should be downloaded again. If it hasn't changed, don't get it down again.

What do you think about this subject?

Thank you, best.

Comment: Hey @HüseyinErenGüler, did my answer help you solve your problem?

Comment: I can say that I solved the problem in my own way. But your suggestion was a big help to me. Thanks.

Comment: That's nice, do mark the answer as correct, if you think it helped you and might help others looking for answer, I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways, by which I think you can do this. One way would be to put this info on Firebase Database.

With database that can get you information so fast, you can always put all your data on it.

By this, I mean that when you first upload an image to Firebase Storage then you can add a `changeTimestamp` field, which has the timestamp of the time when the image was added.

And you can update that field whenever there is change in your Firebase Storage, simply. And then you can just understand if something has changed or not in your storage based on recency of the `changeTimestamp` value.

Another way, would be to use Cloud Functions for Firebase, that can literally solve most of your problems which need server, without server.

Take a look at it here: [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Answer (score 0):

you should use this listener

```
 ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
Post changedPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
System.out.println("The updated post title is: " + changedPost.title);

// write yout code
}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

reference [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)